# Битрикс отбор ($arFilter) свойств элементов инфоблока по нескольким значениям поля через API

Tags: php, битрикс

Все мы знаем о методе `IN` в базе sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE value IN(1,2,3)
```

Нужно реализовать похожий отбор для свойств элементов инфоблока с ID = `INFOBLOCK_ID`.

Как получить данные свойств инфоблока `INFOBLOCK_ID`, символьный код `CODE` которых входит в массив `array('символьныйКод1', 'символьныйКод2')`.

Пробовал код ниже, но не работает:

```
<?
$filter = array(
    'IBLOCK_ID' => INFOBLOCK_ID,
    'CODE' => array('символьныйКод1', 'символьныйКод2')
);
$res = CIBlockProperty::GetList(array(), $filter);
while ($field = $res->Fetch()) {
    // не работает - отбирает все свойства инфоблока 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В старой версии API никак, там жестко в документации прописано "только строка" (маски тоже не работают).

Можешь использовать D7.

Вот получается таким твой код:

```
$filter = array(
    'IBLOCK_ID' => INFOBLOCK_ID,
    'CODE' => array('символьныйКод1', 'символьныйКод2')
);
$res = Bitrix\Iblock\PropertyTable::getList(array(
    'filter' => $filter
));
while ($field = $res->Fetch()) {
    // все должно работать
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Отмечу, что корректнее заменить `$res->Fetch()` на `$res->fetch()`, хотя и без правок запустится.